# ¿ Como cambio la fuente teniendo estilos bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, fuentes

Estoy tratando de crear una web. Me ayudaron compañeros como Camilo Vasquez, añadiendo las librerías bootstrap para crear una barra de navegación.
También tengo hoja de estilos propia y quería cambiar el tamaño de la fuente de esta barra de navegación, pero no soy capaz.
Por otro lado, he quitado las columnas laterales, las he comentado en el código, pero tampoco se como ampliar el texto a toda la pagina.
Dejo la muestra de lo que tengo por si pueden ayudarme, seguro que es sencillo, pero llevo desde ayer intentado arreglarlo sin éxito.
Muchas gracias.

```css
body {
        min-width: 630px;
    }
    
    #container{
        margin-top: 51px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    #container .column {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #footer {
        clear: both;
    }
    
    /* IE hack */
    * html #left {
        left: 150px;
    }
    
    /*Haz que las columnas tengan la misma altura que las otras */
    #container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /*Solución para el pie de página */
    * html body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    * html #footer-wrapper {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 10010px;
        margin-bottom: -10000px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    /* Aesthetics */
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family:Sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    
    p {
        color: #555;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul a {
        color: darkgreen;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #header, #footer {
        font-size: large;
        background: #BCCE98;
    }
    
    #left {
        background: #DAE9BC;
    }
    
    #right {
        background: #F7FDEB;
    }
    
    #center {
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    #container .column {
        padding-top: 1em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">-->
    <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/icon.ico" />
    <!-- ESTO LO TENGO GRACIAS A UN COMPAÑERO, CAMILO VASQUEZ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <title>Principal</title>
    </head>
<body>
        <header id="header">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
            
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                                Logo
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Navbar links -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">SOGRE MI</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">SOBRE MI</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                                        <li><a href="#">ESTUDIOS</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
            
                            <!-- Search -->
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                            </form>
            
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container -->
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div id="container">
            
               <!-- <nav id="left" class="column col-md-2">
                    <h3>DATOS PERSONALES</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="curriculum-1.html">Curriculum</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="estudios-2.html">Estudios</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="experiencia-3.html">Experiencia</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="proyectos-4.html">Proyectos</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="futuro-5.html">Futuro</a></li>
            
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                  
                    <h3>Redes sociales</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009248037432">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/laparramiguel">Twitter</a></li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>-->
            
                </nav>
            
                <main id="center" class="column col-md-8">
                    <article>
                    
                        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
                        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
                         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
                         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
                                
                        
                        <P></P>
                        <h2>CURRICULUM</h2>
                        <p>Aquí encontrareis los <a href="curriculum-1.html">trabajos </a>por los que me he movido, siendo el transporte por carretera lo que mas he desempeñado estos 
                                últimos años. </p>
                        <h2></h2>
                        <h2>ESPEDIENTE ACADEMICO</h2>
                        <p>Mis estudios no son muchos, deje pronto la escuela para trabajar. Pero en los últimos años he retomado el tema académico,
                                formandome en el tema de la programación y aunque llevo poco tiempo ya he creado alguna <a href="proyectos-4.html">humilde aplicacion.</a></p>
                        
                        <h2>EXPERIENCIA</h2>
            
                        <p>Como ya he dicho, mi carrera de desarrollador no a echo mas que empezar, y son pocos y pequeños los <a href="proyectos-4.html">proyectos </a>que he 
                            creado,   pero estoy dedicandome plenamente en sacar una aplicación que espero tenga una buena aceptación y porque no, 
                            triunfar
                        </p>
                        <h2></h2>
                        <h2></h2>
                
            
                         <!-- MANERA DE VER UN PDF PINCHANDO EN ENLACE 

                        <a href="pdf/html.pdf">Haz clic aquí para el PDF</a>  -->
                        <object  data="pdf/html.pdf"></object>
                        
                        <iframe  src="pdf/html.pdf"></iframe>
                       
                       
                    
                    </article>                              
                </main>
            
               <!-- <div id="right" class="column col-md-2">
                    <h3>FOTO DE PERFIL</h3>
                    <p><script>generateText(1)</script></p>
                </div>-->
            
            </div>
            
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
                <footer id="footer"><p>Footer...</p></footer>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para solucionar tu problema en cuanto al tamaño de fuente de la barra de navegación solo basta con quitar el `font-size: large;` que tienes en los estilos de `#header` o bien podrías cambiar su valor por un valor numérico en pixeles.

Ahora si quieres que el contenido sea de todo el ancho de la pantalla puedes cambiar esto `<main id="center" class="column col-md-8">` por esto `<main id="center" class="column col-md-12">`, con esta instrucción le dices a ese elemento que ocupe las 12 columnas en las que divide Bootstrap la ventana del navegador. (también podrías cambiar la clase `col-md-12` por `container-fluid`)

```css
body {
        min-width: 630px;
    }
    
    #container{
        margin-top: 51px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    
    #container .column {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #footer {
        clear: both;
    }
    
    /* IE hack */
    * html #left {
        left: 150px;
    }
    
    /*Haz que las columnas tengan la misma altura que las otras */
    #container {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    /*Solución para el pie de página */
    * html body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    * html #footer-wrapper {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 10010px;
        margin-bottom: -10000px;
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    /* Aesthetics */
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family:Sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    
    p {
        color: #555;
    }
    
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    nav ul a {
        color: darkgreen;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #header, #footer {
        background: #BCCE98;
    }
    
    #left {
        background: #DAE9BC;
    }
    
    #right {
        background: #F7FDEB;
    }
    
    #center {
        background: #fff;
    }
    
    #container .column {
        padding-top: 1em;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">-->
    <link rel="icon" href="imagenes/icon.ico" />
    <!-- ESTO LO TENGO GRACIAS A UN COMPAÑERO, CAMILO VASQUEZ -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <title>Principal</title>
    </head>
<body>
        <header id="header">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container">
                        <!-- Logo and responsive toggle -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
            
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> 
                                Logo
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Navbar links -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active">
                                    <a href="#">PRINCIPAL</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">SOGRE MI</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">SOBRE MI</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">SOBRE MI <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="about-us">
                                        <li><a href="#">ESTUDIOS</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">PROYECTOS</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">CURRICULUM</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
            
                            <!-- Search -->
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
                            </form>
            
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container -->
                </nav>
            </header>
            <div id="container">
            
               <!-- <nav id="left" class="column col-md-2">
                    <h3>DATOS PERSONALES</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="curriculum-1.html">Curriculum</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="estudios-2.html">Estudios</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="experiencia-3.html">Experiencia</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="proyectos-4.html">Proyectos</a></li><br>
                        <li><a target="_blank" href="futuro-5.html">Futuro</a></li>
            
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                  
                    <h3>Redes sociales</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009248037432">Facebook</a></li>
                        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/laparramiguel">Twitter</a></li>
                        <!--<li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                    </ul>-->
            
                </nav>
            
                <main id="center" class="column col-md-12">
                    <article>
                    
                        <h1>BIENVENIDOS A MI SITIO WEB...</h1>
                        <p>Hola, me llamo Miguel y os voy a presentar mi sitio web, el cual estoy creando mientras realizo un curso de actívate. 
                         En principio esta creado para mostrar mi perfil, experiencia laboral, formación académica y todos los conocimientos que 
                         vaya adquiriendo en el curso. </p>
                                
                        
                        <P></P>
                        <h2>CURRICULUM</h2>
                        <p>Aquí encontrareis los <a href="curriculum-1.html">trabajos </a>por los que me he movido, siendo el transporte por carretera lo que mas he desempeñado estos 
                                últimos años. </p>
                        <h2></h2>
                        <h2>ESPEDIENTE ACADEMICO</h2>
                        <p>Mis estudios no son muchos, deje pronto la escuela para trabajar. Pero en los últimos años he retomado el tema académico,
                                formandome en el tema de la programación y aunque llevo poco tiempo ya he creado alguna <a href="proyectos-4.html">humilde aplicacion.</a></p>
                        
                        <h2>EXPERIENCIA</h2>
            
                        <p>Como ya he dicho, mi carrera de desarrollador no a echo mas que empezar, y son pocos y pequeños los <a href="proyectos-4.html">proyectos </a>que he 
                            creado,   pero estoy dedicandome plenamente en sacar una aplicación que espero tenga una buena aceptación y porque no, 
                            triunfar
                        </p>
                        <h2></h2>
                        <h2></h2>
                
            
                         <!-- MANERA DE VER UN PDF PINCHANDO EN ENLACE 

                        <a href="pdf/html.pdf">Haz clic aquí para el PDF</a>  -->
                        <object  data="pdf/html.pdf"></object>
                        
                        <iframe  src="pdf/html.pdf"></iframe>
                       
                       
                    
                    </article>                              
                </main>
            
               <!-- <div id="right" class="column col-md-2">
                    <h3>FOTO DE PERFIL</h3>
                    <p><script>generateText(1)</script></p>
                </div>-->
            
            </div>
            
        <div id="footer-wrapper">
                <footer id="footer"><p>Footer...</p></footer>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias compañero, tu de nuevo, le tendre que poner tu nombre a la web.                       Gracias...

Comment: Bueno, he puesto la que no era.....